# My Mac doesn't allow installation of any software

Tags: macos, terminal, install, homebrew, python

[image]

Every time I try to install any software on my Mac, it comes up with an error. I have scoured the net and have followed advice which includes checking if there's enough space (which I have), checking if my user has authorisation (which I have), checking if my internet connection is strong and stable (which it is). I have attached a screenshot of the problem, and it's so frustrating as I have the python 3.8.5 and have tried to `brew install` the latest Python 3.10 via the terminal, but it wouldn't update it for some reason when i type `python --version`

This also happens when I try to install other types of software too and it's honestly so frustrating!

I would appreciate all the help and assistance I can get.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error? When you say "Any software", do you mean Mac App Store? Installer Packages? Or is it just brew? What OS version are you on? What happens if you use the command `python3` instead of `python`?

Comment: Screenshot missing - if you can't post to here put it somewhere public like imgur, post the link here & a higher-rep user can inline it for you.

Comment: Have attached the error! Any software as in anything I try installing from the net. I am on the latest OS version. If i use the python3 to find the version it says 3.8.5 and when i try python it just says: (zsh: command not found: python3.4) -@benwiggy

Comment: Is your Mac managed by your organisation/school/employer? Can you install applications from the Mac App Store?

Comment: Hey @nohillside, i own it outright. It's not managed by any organisation/school/employer. That being said it does have an eduroam profile that we at uni have to use to access wifi.

Comment: And when you install software, are you using the WiFi in your university or the one at home?

Comment: The error above is not related to installing Python from Homebrew.

Comment: @nohillside Well so i tried using installing this at home, and it's the same issue. I really don't know what's happening. This has happened even when I was away from university.

Comment: @MarcWilson Yep. Because I couldn't get it to update via Homebrew, I thought I should physically install the package from their webpage. However,  it gave me the error mentioned in the post. This has also been happening with other Software Installs, but luckily, i've not had a lot to install, as of late.

Comment: Is this a new Mac you installed from scratch, or did you transfer data etc from an old Mac into it? Also, do you have an Apple Store close by, might be easier to diagnose the issue while having access to your system.

Comment: This is almost a new mac as I bought it for uni. And no I havent  transferred any data from my old Mac. There’s an Apple Store nearby. Will check them out. Any ideas on your end? @nohillside

Comment: What OS version do you have? Have you tried installing python directly from python.org? If you have Xcode installed (or Xcode command line tools), then you get python3 included. (version 3.8 on Monterey; 3.9 on Ventura).

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't answerable with the data you provided, but here is how to find out what's happening - and maybe we can help you remotely if you can't see the issue once you get at the logs for the install.

To get more information on the problem, try the following:

1. Open the Console app.
2. Click on "Start streaming", or the start button at the top.
3. Run the installer.
4. In Console, press Pause.
5. Search for 'install', and see if anything useful pops up with a time stamp that corresponds to the installation action.

Post the results in this question or ask a follow up as you wish.